# prevent RadSideDrawer from opening

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-nativescript

I have a RadSideDrawer that is apparently available through the whole app. Now, there are some routes that I want to prevent the drawer from showing.

I thought of the logical way of doing this is by listening the onDrawerOpening event. However, the event object has no way to prevent the sidedrawer from transiotioning.

Is there a way to handle this scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may toggle [gesturesEnabled](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/professional-ui-components/SideDrawer/programmatic#the-gesturesenabled-property) property of SideDrawer whenever you want to enable / disable the swipe gestures.

There is also [allowEdgeSwipe](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/radsidedrawer#allowedgeswipe) which can be used to enable / disable only the open gesture since v4.2.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, one of them is to disable the swipe. I have created a playground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=lCe2Tc).

```
@ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) public drawerComponent: 
RadSideDrawerComponent;    
if (ios) {
        this.drawerComponent.nativeElement.ios.defaultSideDrawer.allowEdgeSwipe = false;
    } else {
        this.drawerComponent.nativeElement.android.setTouchTargetThreshold(0);
    }
```